# SwiftUI and CombineLatest with more than 4 values

Tags: swiftui, combine

I'm starting to experiment with SwiftUI and I have a situation where I want the latest combination of 5 sliders. I had everything working with 4 sliders, using `CombineLatest4`, then realized I need another slider, but there's no `CombineLatest5`.

Any help appreciated.

To clarify the working 4-slider version:

```
Publishers
    .CombineLatest4($slider1, $slider2, $slider3, $slider4)
    .debounce(for: 0.3, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
    .subscribe(subscriber)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`CombineLatest2(CombineLatest3, CombineLatest2)` should do the trick, shouldn't it?

Comment: Hmm... seems reasonable, but I get `Use of unresolved identifier 'CombineLatest'` when nesting them this way. I'll add my "working" `CombineLatest4()` version to the question, just for clarity.

Comment: How silly these CombineLatestX look... Cannot it take an array?

Comment: @paulz Yes... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69774495/chaining-n-requests-in-combine/69774881#69774881

Answer (score 7):

Note - solution extracted from the question

---

Okay, getting the syntax figured out, @Daniel-t was right. I just needed to create the sub-publishers:

```
let paramsOne = Publishers
    .CombineLatest3($slider1, $slider2, $slider3)
        
let paramsTwo = Publishers
    .CombineLatest($slider4, $slider5)
        
paramsOne.combineLatest(paramsTwo)
    .debounce(for: 0.3, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
    .subscribe(subscriber)
```

Note that I also had to change what my subscriber expected as input from `(Double, Double, Double, Double, Double)` to `((Double, Double, Double), (Double, Double))`, and that the compiler gave me a misleading and confusing error (something about Schedulers) until I figured out that the input type was wrong.

Comment: This is by far the best solution without having to add extensions. However do you happen to know how to use naming instead of numbers

example"
paramsOne.slider1 instead of paramsOne.0

Answer (score 4):

You can add `combineLatest` functionality for as many publishers as you need. Below is an example of rather irritating form that will allow sign-in only when all the fields are not empty.

```
import Combine

final class SignUpVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var email: String = ""
    @Published var password1: String = ""
    @Published var password2: String = ""
    @Published var password3: String = ""
    @Published var password4: String = ""
    @Published var password5: String = ""
    @Published var password6: String = ""
    
    @Published var isValid = false
    
    private var cancellableSet: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    init() {
        [$email, $password1, $password2, $password3, $password4, $password5, $password6]
            .combineLatest()
            .map { $0.allSatisfy({ !$0.isEmpty })}
            .assign(to: \.isValid, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellableSet)
    }
    
}

extension Collection where Element: Publisher {
    func combineLatest() -> AnyPublisher<[Element.Output], Element.Failure> {
        var wrapped = map { $0.map { [$0] }.eraseToAnyPublisher() }
        while wrapped.count > 1 {
            wrapped = makeCombinedChunks(input: wrapped)
        }
        return wrapped.first?.eraseToAnyPublisher() ?? Empty().eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

private func makeCombinedChunks<Output, Failure: Swift.Error>(
    input: [AnyPublisher<[Output], Failure>]
) -> [AnyPublisher<[Output], Failure>] {
    sequence(
        state: input.makeIterator(),
        next: { it in it.next().map { ($0, it.next(), it.next(), it.next()) } }
    )
    .map { chunk in
        guard let second = chunk.1 else { return chunk.0 }
        
        guard let third = chunk.2 else {
            return chunk.0
                .combineLatest(second)
                .map { $0.0 + $0.1 }
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        
        guard let fourth = chunk.3 else {
            return chunk.0
                .combineLatest(second, third)
                .map { $0.0 + $0.1 + $0.2 }
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        
        return chunk.0
            .combineLatest(second, third, fourth)
            .map { $0.0 + $0.1 + $0.2 + $0.3 }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like:

```
extension Publisher {
public func combineLatest<P, Q, R, Y>(
    _ publisher1: P,
    _ publisher2: Q,
    _ publisher3: R,
    _ publisher4: Y) ->
    AnyPublisher<(Self.Output, P.Output, Q.Output, R.Output, Y.Output), Self.Failure> where
    P: Publisher,
    Q: Publisher,
    R: Publisher,
    Y: Publisher,
    Self.Failure == P.Failure,
    P.Failure == Q.Failure,
    Q.Failure == R.Failure,
    R.Failure == Y.Failure {
    Publishers.CombineLatest(combineLatest(publisher1, publisher2, publisher3), publisher4).map { tuple, publisher4Value in
        (tuple.0, tuple.1, tuple.2, tuple.3, publisher4Value)
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}
```

and call it like:

```
publisher1.combineLatest(publisher2, publisher3, publisher4, publisher5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Leonid's answer: if you need support for a transform function, you need something like this:

```swift
    public func combineLatest<P, Q, R, Y, T>(
            _ publisher1: P,
            _ publisher2: Q,
            _ publisher3: R,
            _ publisher4: Y,
            _ transform: @escaping (Self.Output, P.Output, Q.Output, R.Output, Y.Output) -> T) ->
            AnyPublisher<T, Self.Failure> where
    P: Publisher,
    Q: Publisher,
    R: Publisher,
    Y: Publisher,
    Self.Failure == P.Failure,
    P.Failure == Q.Failure,
    Q.Failure == R.Failure,
    R.Failure == Y.Failure {
        Publishers.CombineLatest(combineLatest(publisher1, publisher2, publisher3), publisher4)
                  .map { tuple, publisher4Value in
                      transform(tuple.0, tuple.1, tuple.2, tuple.3, publisher4Value)
                  }
                  .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```